Is there a way to speed things up, when applying conditional formatting to an Excel sheet from PowerShell?
I'm using the Excel com interface from PowerShell to apply conditional formatting to particular cells. Here is an example excerpt.
        # Conditional formats
        $SafeCheck = $OutputSheet.Range("AI$i")
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlEqual, "TRUE") #good
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlLess, 100)     #good
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlLess, 0)       #warning
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlEqual, "FALSE")#bad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlLess, -100)    #bad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlGreater, 100)  #bad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(1).Interior.Color = $CGood
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(1).Font.Color = $FGood
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(2).Interior.Color = $CGood
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(2).Font.Color = $FGood
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(3).Interior.Color = $CWarn
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(3).Font.Color = $FWarn
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(4).Interior.Color = $CBad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(4).Font.Color = $FBad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(5).Interior.Color = $CBad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(5).Font.Color = $FBad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(6).Interior.Color = $CBad
        $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Item(6).Font.Color = $FBad

Currently it works but it is very slow even with only 30 rows in the column being modified. It seems to spend a lot of time gathering and displaying success messages. Like this.
Application  : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator      : 1480803660
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Type         : 1
Operator     : 3
Formula1     : =TRUE
Formula2     :
Interior     : System.__ComObject
Borders      : System.__ComObject
Font         : System.__ComObject
Text         :
TextOperator :
DateOperator :
NumberFormat :
Priority     : 19
StopIfTrue   : True
AppliesTo    : System.__ComObject
PTCondition  : False
ScopeType    :

Application  : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
Creator      : 1480803660
Parent       : System.__ComObject
Type         : 1
Operator     : 6
Formula1     : =100
Formula2     :
Interior     : System.__ComObject
Borders      : System.__ComObject
Font         : System.__ComObject
Text         :
TextOperator :
DateOperator :
NumberFormat :
Priority     : 20
StopIfTrue   : True
AppliesTo    : System.__ComObject
PTCondition  : False
ScopeType    :

Is there a way to speed this up? I expected it to run very quickly. It works but runs very slowly.

Does this answer your question: Powershell script using Excel running slow?

You can suppress the console output for any methods that return a value (e.g. FormatCOndition.Add - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.formatconditions.add) by capturing the return value - e.g. $null = $SafeCheck.FormatConditions.Add($xlCellValue, $xlEqual, "TRUE"). That might speed things up by a small margin if you're formatting things repeatedly in a tight loop as it won't have to render the output to the console for each instruction...

Also, if you're formatting one row / cell / column at a time that's going to be very slow - if you can format an entire range in one go it'll be an order of magnitude faster. COM instructions have a fairly big overhead, so the less you can do the better.

As you do no have ennough reputation to comment back, it is best to edit your question and cover these background questions and what you already tryed as a possible solution in there.

Thank you, guys, for the great input. Excellent suggestion @iRon, I had not run across that page. I'll definitely use that. Also, a good point mclayton. I am applying the formats to select cells in particular rows one at a time. I will try adding another condition for blank cells to color them normal. Then I can add all of the formats at once. I will test this and comment back in a bit.

I ended up setting the formatting in one row and then using $OutputSheet.Range($StartRange + "2:" + $EndRange + "2").copy() $OutputSheet.Range($StartRange + $i + ":" + $EndRange + $i).Select() $OutputSheet.Range($StartRange + $i + ":" + $EndRange + $i).PasteSpecial(-4122)
to copy and paste it. Much faster. Next I'll try @iRon's suggestion.
